# Do central isometries on complex spaces respect addition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It can be proved that

> Any central isometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation.

So I was wondering whether central isometries on $\mathbb{C}^n$ are also linear transformations. Apparently they are not, since

$f:\mathbb{C}^1\to \mathbb{C}^1$, $f(z) = \overline{z}$ is a central isometry (as $||f(\textbf{x})-f(\textbf{y})||=|f(x)-f(y)|=|\overline{x}-\overline{y}|= |\overline{x-y}|=|x-y|=||\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}||\quad\forall \textbf{x}, \textbf{y}\in \mathbb{C^1}$, $|\cdot|$ is complex absolute value,

and $f(\textbf{0})=\overline{0}=0=\textbf{0}$)

but is not a linear transformation (as $f(cz)=\overline{c}f(z)\neq cf(z)$).
However, I do feel that central isometries on $\mathbb{C}^n$ must respect addition.

So the question is -

> Prove or disprove: Central isometries on $\mathbb{C}^n$ respect
>   addition.

Dictionary of terms:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$) is called an isometry if $||f(\textbf{x})-f(\textbf{y})||=||\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}||\quad \forall \textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$). (We work with the standard inner product and standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$)

An isometry $f$ is called a central isometry if $f(\textbf{0})=\textbf{0}$.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$) is said to respect addition if $f(\textbf{x} + \textbf{y}) = f(\textbf{x}) + f(\textbf{y}) \quad \forall \textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$).

Comment: I think that for a central isometry we must have an **iff** $f(0)=0$, so $z \rightarrow  \bar z$ is not a central isometry.

Comment: @EmilioNovati see edit, i have proved that $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ is a central isometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{C}^{n}$ with the norm coming from the standard Hermitian inner product is isometric to $\mathbf{R}^{2n}$ with the Euclidean norm, your question reduces to the known case of isometries of real Euclidean space. (That is, central isometries do respect vector addition, as well as multiplication by real scalars.)

Comment: That is quite a round about method for the proof. Could we have a proof by working in $\mathbb{C}^n$ itself?

Comment: It seemed "elegant" to me, not "roundabout". :) Anyway, $\mathbf{C}^{n}$ "contains more information than" $\mathbf{R}^{2n}$, so it suffices to forget complex scalar multiplication, then run through the usual proof of looking at distances to elements of a real orthonormal basis. But if you're asking "How would I think to pursue this strategy if I didn't know about $\mathbf{R}^{2n}$?", I don't have a good answer. Normally one seeks arguments requiring "purity of method" in order to _generalize_ (i.e., weaken hypotheses), not to specialize....

Comment: The idea was to generalise the result in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$. Your proof is elegant, I agree. But somehow I feel that it does not show us the geometry in $\mathbb{C}^n$. It only transfers properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$.